# Change value (wrap) of Reflect function in Proxy handler

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I have this;

```js
function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
    console.log('wrapping brain API')
    const handler = {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            console.log('GET', propKey);
            return Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler)
}
```

It works fine when tracing calls, so I can access console or do whatever I want before the function is being called.
But what I want is to further modify the structure of the function `return` value.

I tried changing `handler` to this:

```js
function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
    console.log('wrapping brain API')
    const handler = {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            console.log('GET', propKey);
            const wrap = () => {
                const result = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver)
                return {
                    result: result,
                    api: 'api'
                }
            }
            return wrap
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler)
}
```

But now result is `Reflect` anonymous function instead. If I call it in handler, I get another error.

Comment: because you return `wrap` function, not a call of it. try `return wrap()`

Answer (score 0):

Following @Kosh indication:

```js
function traceMethodCalls(obj) {
    console.log('wrapping brain API')
    const handler = {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            const origMethod = target[propKey]
            return function (...args) {
                let result = origMethod.apply(this, args)
                return {
                    result: result,
                    api: 'api'
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(obj, handler)
}
```

So without `Reflect.get` it works fine.